# Contus hd video share... I would like remove html5 player

Tags: javascript, php, html, flash, video

I have installed Contus HD Video share for joomla on my site.
Anyway I have a problem. I want to remove html5 player and keep the flash player. I asked the support, but they said it's impossible to do.

But I found the code.

```
<!-- HTML5 player starts here -->
        <div id="htmlplayer">
            <?php
            ## Generate details for HTML5 player
            if ($this->homepageaccess == 'true') {
                if ($htmlVideoDetails->filepath == "File" || $htmlVideoDetails->filepath == "FFmpeg" || $htmlVideoDetails->filepath == "Url") {
                    $current_path       = "components/com_contushdvideoshare/videos/";
                    if ($htmlVideoDetails->filepath == "Url") {                             ## For URL Method videos
                        if ($htmlVideoDetails->streameroption == 'rtmp') {
                            $rtmp       = str_replace('rtmp', 'http', $htmlVideoDetails->streamerpath);
                            $video      = $rtmp . '_definst_/mp4:'. $htmlVideoDetails->videourl . '/playlist.m3u8';   ## For RTMP videos
                        } else {
                            $video      = $htmlVideoDetails->videourl;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $video          = JURI::base() . $current_path . $htmlVideoDetails->videourl;   ## For upload Method videos
                    }
                    ?>
                    <video id="video" src="<?php echo $video; ?>" width="<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>" autobuffer controls onerror="failed(event)">
                        Html5 Not support This video Format.
                    </video>
                        <?php
                    } elseif ($htmlVideoDetails->filepath == "Youtube") {                   ## For youtube videos
                        if (preg_match('/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/', $htmlVideoDetails->videourl, $vresult)) {
                            $urlArray = explode("=", $vresult[0]);
                            $videoid = trim($urlArray[1]);
                            $video = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoid";
                        ?>
                        <iframe width="<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>" src="<?php echo $video; ?>" class="iframe_frameborder" ></iframe>
                        <?php
                    } else if (strpos($htmlVideoDetails->videourl, 'dailymotion') > 0) {    ## For dailymotion videos
                        $video = $htmlVideoDetails->videourl;
                        ?>
                        <iframe width="<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>" src="<?php echo $video; ?>" class="iframe_frameborder" ></iframe>
                        <?php
                    } else if (strpos($htmlVideoDetails->videourl, 'viddler') > 0) {        ## For viddler videos
                        $imgstr = explode("/", $htmlVideoDetails->videourl);
                        ?>
                        <iframe id="viddler-<?php echo $imgstr; ?>" src="//www.viddler.com/embed/<?php echo $imgstr; ?>/?f=1&autoplay=0&player=full&secret=26392356&loop=false&nologo=false&hd=false" width="<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
            <?php
        }
    }
} else {               ## Restricted video design part 
    ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .login_msg{vertical-align: middle;height:<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>px;display: table-cell; color: #fff;}
                            .login_msg a{background: #999; color:#fff; padding: 5px;}
                        </style>

                <div id="video" style="height:<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>px; background-color:#000000; position: relative;" >
                    <div class="login_msg">
                    <h3>Please login to watch this video</h3>
                    <a href="<?php if (!empty($player_icons['login_page_url'])) { echo $player_icons['login_page_url']; } else { echo "#"; } ?>"><?php echo JText::_('HDVS_LOGIN'); ?></a>
                </div>
                </div>
<?php } ?>
        </div>

                    <?php } else { ?>

         <!-- Flash player Start -->
        <div id="flashplayer">
            <embed wmode="opaque" src="<?php echo $playerpath; ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="baserefJHDV=<?php echo $details1['baseurl']; ?><?php echo $baseref; ?>"  style="width:<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>px; height:<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>px" />
        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
        <!--Platform check-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var txt = navigator.platform;
            function failed(e)
            {
                if (txt == 'iPod' || txt == 'iPad' || txt == 'iPhone' || windo == "Windows Phone" || txt == 'Linux armv7l' || txt == 'Linux armv6l')
                {
                    alert('Player doesnot support this video.');
                }
            }
        </script>
        <!-- HTML5 PLAYER  END -->
```

As you can see, there are 2 player, html5 and flash player. The script try to find if the users are using mobile or computer desktop and then provide html5 or flash player. But I don't want the script provide html5 player in any case. Can you please give me an help? I tried to remove this script

```
 <video id="video" src="<?php echo $video; ?>" width="<?php echo $player_values['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $player_values['height']; ?>" autobuffer controls onerror="failed(event)">
                    Html5 Not support This video Format.
                </video>
```

But then the page become completely blank... I don't know what I can do...

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but what's wrong with HTML5 video...?

Comment: Hi... the problem is that in my Joomla site I activated the Cache plugin. This means that if a user with mobile device open a video... the script provide the html5 player and then the cache save the html5 player and provide the same player even for computer desktop users... And I don't like that... For example, in firefox 41 for computer desktop, the flash player start fine but html5 give error.